US Visa OFC booked, Consular appointment pending
There are issues with new visa appointment portal. Yesterday I rescheduled OFC appointment to an earlier date but when rescheduling Consular Appointment I got the message "No slots available".
This was not happening on previous portal. The new portal was even worse before, when you are stuck in midway like this, you will remain like this for a month also.
How to get out of this situation?

They have fixed this issue. You don't have to do anything but wait for 7-8 hours maybe.
If you were unable to book Consular appointment, they will cancel the OFC after some time. I booked at night and in the morning OFC was cancelled.
